# Embed JavaScript in a button

Tags: javascript, html, button

How can I embed my rock, paper, scissors game in a button?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>


<button onclick="rockPaperScissors()">Click me</button>



<script  type="text/javascript">
var rockPaperScissors(
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
} console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);


var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
if (choice1 === choice2) {
    confirm("The result is a tie!";)
    }
    else if(choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
        confirm("rock wins";)
    }
    else {
        confirm("paper wins";)
    }
}

//second one

    else if(choice1 === "paper") {
    if (choice2 === "rock") {
        confirm("paper wins";)
    }
    else {
        confirm("scissors wins";)
    }
}

//third one

    else if(choice1 === "scissors") {
    if (choice2 === "rock") {
        confirm("rock wins";)
    }
    else {
        confirm("scissors wins";)
    }
}
};

)

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: don't you have a syntax error at `var rockPaperScissors(`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more typo in there... corrected code is below including the first line of the script `var rockPaperScissors = function(){` and confirm should always look like `confirm("paper wins");`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>


<button onclick="rockPaperScissors()">Click me</button>



<script  type="text/javascript">
var rockPaperScissors = function(){
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
 computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
 computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
 computerChoice = "scissors";
} console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);


var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
if (choice1 === choice2) {
    confirm("The result is a tie!");
    }
    else if(choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
        confirm("rock wins");
    }
    else {
        confirm("paper wins");
    }
}

//second one

    else if(choice1 === "paper") {
    if (choice2 === "rock") {
        confirm("paper wins");
    }
    else {
        confirm("scissors wins");
    }
}

//third one

    else if(choice1 === "scissors") {
    if (choice2 === "rock") {
        confirm("rock wins");
    }
    else {
        confirm("scissors wins");
    }
}
};
};

</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here:

`var rockPaperScissors(`

You need `rockPaperScissors` to be a function, not a variable.

Try the following code to make `rockPaperScissors` be a function:

`function rockPaperScissors() {}`

or

`var rockPaperScissors = function() {}`

then put your relevant code inside of the braces (`{ }`).

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared your rockPaperScissors function correctly. So, when the program tries to call it, it does not work.

Try

```
function rockPaperScissors() {
  // put your code in here
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.